# How to perform a left join in my dynamic pivot query so it still returns rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

My pivot table is working only when there is data in the table (tempCounts) because I am performing a inner join.

How can I return rows regardless if the `#tempCounts` table has matching records or not?   Sometimes the `#tempCounts` table is empty, but I still need to return the records from the `Users` table.

```
 SET @query
    = N'SELECT  
                ParticipantEmail,
                Age,' + @cols
      + 
      N' 
         from (
            SELECT
                u.ParticipantEmail,
                u.Age,
                tc.RegionName,
                tc.Count
            FROM Users u
                INNER JOIN #tempCounts tc ON ee.ParticipantEmail COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = tc.CustomerEmail
            ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum(Count)
            for RegionName in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p ';
```

I tried using a left join but it doesn't work, I'm guessing because of the pivot clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your example, but I don't think the LEFT JOIN and PIVOT combo is your problem, I worked up a simple test case (forgive the shortened names) and it works fine

```
with cteCust as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('Alice', 25), ('Bob', 22)
        , ('Chris', 27), ('Doug', 21), ('Eve', 28)
        ) as Cust (Part, Age)
), cteTempCount as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('Alice', 'US', 5), ('Alice', 'EU', 2), ('Alice', 'GB', 4) 
        , ('Chris', 'GB', 3), ('Chris', 'JP', 6)
        , ('Doug', 'JP', 7), ('Doug', 'EU', 4), ('Doug', 'EU', 9)
        , ('Eve', 'US', 1), ('Eve', 'GB', 2),  ('Eve', 'JP', 5)
    ) as TC(Part, Regn, RCount)
) 
SELECT Part, Age, US, EU
FROM (SELECT u.Part, u.age, Regn, RCount FROM cteCust as U 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTempCount as TC on U.Part = TC.Part) as X
PIVOT (SUM(RCount) FOR Regn in (US, EU)) as P;
```

gives results

```
Part    Age US  EU
Alice   25  5   2
Bob 22  NULL    NULL
Chris   27  NULL    NULL
Doug    21  NULL    13
Eve 28  1   NULL
```

which is giving a results row even for users with no matches in the desired regions (Chris) or no matches in TempCount whatsoever (Bob).

Is it possible some of the RegionNames aren't making good column names?

Or maybe whatever is consuming this output is having trouble with NULL values?

Maybe @cols is malformed?

Comment: Thanks.  Hey curious, would it be possible to merge 2 columns together for the dynamic column names?  Like in your example the column Regn.  Say there was another column, could you merge the columns so the headers have something like ```Regn + '(' + RegnCode + ')'```  I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @coolbreeze, I'm not sure, but I think so. You can alias the columns so the headers display more information, so I think you could generate it programatically. You'd need to form (A for AtSign)AColHeads from ACols and use AColHeads in the SELECT that pulls from the PIVOT. It would give a SELECT that looks like this "SELECT Part, Age, US as [US(13)], EU as [EU(21)]". How are you generating ACols? Please report back what you can, I'm interested in what can be done here.